# Workflow without lock and edit option

Tags: workflow

Is it possible to have workflow without lock and edit option.

Also the item version should increment only it had reached the final workflow state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a good idea.

If you want remove the requirement to `Lock and Edit` an item then you can update the following setting to `false`:

```xml
<!--
  REQUIRE LOCK BEFORE EDITING
  If true, the user must have a lock on a document before
  they can edit it, otherwise it is always ready for editing    
-->
<setting name="RequireLockBeforeEditing" value="false" />
```

Since the item no longer requires locking, a version is not automatically created when a user edits. In order to create a new version, the user must manually do it from the version tab or version selector. The main problem however is that an author is still able to edit the fields of the current version of an item and immediately publish it without going through the approval process. In theory, you could ensure the user does not have `Workflow State Write` permission for the Final Workflow Step:

[image: Edit Item Final Workflow Step]

However this does not work as expected, although you get a warning the user is still able to edit the fields and publish the item (this may be a bug, I've never worked with this setting disabled).

If you want to minimize the *Lock and Edit* flow then instead consider the following setting to `true`:

```xml
<!--
  AUTOMATIC UNLOCK ON SAVED
  If true, then a saved item is automatically unlocked saving.
-->
<setting name="AutomaticUnlockOnSaved" value="true" />
```

This will cause the item to be Unlocked Automatically after a user saves it, although submitting for workflow will remove the lock, it does minimize disruption when multiple users need to edit an item.

Regarding version numbers, it will *always* increment when a new version is created. The item version is what you are saving your changes against and therefore it **must** increment immediately. You are then approving the item version in the final workflow step. It is not possible to only increment the number once it has reached the final workflow state.

Comment: Thanks Jammy, This works while adding new version. The new version is added to workflow