# A version is not automatically created when a user edits an item

Tags: sitecore-client

I have created a new non-admin user role. As expected, when the user edits an item, they need to click the 'Lock and Edit item' and a new version is automatically created when the user edits.

But, I have also encountered that it will not create a new version automatically when the user edits the item.

Any advise, pls?

Comment: Does it work for any other item? it this item in a workflow?

Comment: This is answered here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7809/workflow-without-lock-and-edit-option

Comment: yes, it does work for other items. The item (with issue) is in the final workflow.